# how to initialize the jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

Am having problems with Instantiation or how to initialize the validation engine. i have the locale right but i dont know how to attend to this part :

**$("#form.id").validationEngine(action or options);**

when i put the form id as "formID", it stops the get functions from data values in the form from the database. the java script is overwritten. the html as below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
            <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js" type="text/
    javascript"></script>
    <script src="validate/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="validate/js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="validate/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formID").validationEngine('attach');
           });
        </script>
        <form>
            <table>
             <tr>
               <td colspan="4"><div align="center"><strong>Applicant Information</strong></div></td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right">Sur Name:</div></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="validate[required] text-input" name="surname" id="surname" /></td>
                <td><div align="right">First Name:</div></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="validate[required] text-input" name="fname" id="fname" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right">Email Address:</div></td>
                <td><input class="validate[required,custom[email]]" type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
                <td><div align="right">Nursing school:</div></td>
                <td><select name="nursingsch" id="nursingsch">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Graduate Free</option>
                    </select></td>
              </tr>
             </table>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </form>
        </center>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: `jquery.validate.min.js` must be after `jquery.js`

Comment: That is done but still no solution.

Comment: have you checked for any console errors on browser?

Comment: Yes, no errors am using firebug

Comment: can you reproduce your issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: what is jsfiddle? give me links

Comment: JSFiddle is the online editer where you can run your html code by including jquery libraries, css and any other external files. See [this](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/) for understanding of jsfiddle.

Comment: Send for me and share the solution